i can't do shadow vtable hooking
I tried doing the "Shadow VMT" where I replace the whole Virtual Table with my own.
I don't know where I made the mistake, the address of class changed but the hook didn't work.
Here is my code (DLL):
__int64(__fastcall* sub_original)(void*);

__int64 sub_hooked(void* arg)
{
    std::printf("~ welcome\n");
    return sub_original(arg);
}

void do_stuff()
{
    auto vtable = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t**>((std::uintptr_t)GetModuleHandleA(NULL) + (std::uintptr_t)0x3008);
    
    std::size_t num_virtual_methods = {};
    while (vtable[num_virtual_methods])
        num_virtual_methods += 1;
    
    auto allocated_vtable = new std::uintptr_t[num_virtual_methods];
    std::memcpy(allocated_vtable, vtable, num_virtual_methods * sizeof(std::uintptr_t));

    *(void**)&sub_original = allocated_vtable[1];
    
    allocated_vtable[1] = (std::uintptr_t)&sub_hooked;
    
    *(void**)&vtable = allocated_vtable;
}

The executable:
class Example
{
public:
    virtual void hello() = 0;
    virtual void haha() = 0;
};

class Obj : public Example
{
public:
    virtual void hello() override {
        printf("hey, 0x%p\n", this);
    }

    virtual void haha() override {
        printf("haha, 0x%p\n", this);
    }
};

void do_stuff( ) {
    Obj* obj = new Obj;

    while (true) {
        obj->haha( );
        Sleep(5000);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread(do_stuff).detach();
    while(true){}
    return 0;
}

The reversed executable:
.rdata:0000000140003008 ??_7Obj@@6B@  dq offset sub_140007220
.rdata:0000000140003010               dq offset sub_140007240

Some debug logs from console:
haha, 0x000001326C382810
[>] swapping vtable (0x00007FF6C76F3008, vmt[0] = 0x00007FF6C76F7220, vmt[1] = 0x00007FF6C76F7240)
[>] old vtable -> 0x00007FF6C76F3008, new vtable -> 0x000001E8D320A560
haha, 0x000001E8D3201A00

Are you looking for a well-formed C++ compliant solution, or "behind the scenes" vtable pointer manipulation (i.e., undefined behavior as far as C++ is concerned)?

C++ does not require there be such a thing as a vtable for an object, or if it exists, for it to be used at each call site.
Your compiler can see that do_stuff is equivalent to
while (true) {
    printf("haha, 0x%p\n", /* some pointer value that doesn't change */);
    Sleep(5000);
}

and it has emitted object code that behaves consistent with that, ignoring your modifications to the internal structures it created for Obj.

I think you don't understand what I'm trying to do. I inject the DLL and I want to replace the vtable generated by compiler of the executable. I'm not writing the code inside the executable, only the DLL. You are now showing the code inside executable.

@reiizl I know what you are trying to do. It just isn't guaranteed to work. obj->haha( ) is not required to use the vtable of Obj, so even if you have "successfully" replaced it, there can be places where it appears you haven't

@reiizl no, the issue is that what you are trying to do is undefined behaviour. Banish from your mind the idea that you can consistently change the behaviour of a particular member function by fiddling with the executable at runtime. Functions can be inlined, even virtual ones, at which point there are source calls that do not appear in the resulting executable

@reiizl C++ explicitly has the as-if rule. "virtual function call" is not observable behaviour
